# WebGL doesn't work when VNC server is turned on

Tags: 20.04, vnc, lxde, tightvncserver, webgl

I don't know why but when I turn on my laptop, WebGL works both in Chromium and Firefox. But, when I turn on VNC server, WebGL will stop working. It doesn't work both in VNC session and on my screen.

I'm using LXDE on Ubuntu 20.04, I know that it is not supported but I wanted a minimal desktop.
Oh and I'm running tightvncserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this. The problem is in VNC server I used. I simply installed TigerVNC instead of tightvnc and it fixed it.

```
sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server tigervnc-xorg-extension tigervnc-viewer
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)